# Calculate - partial update of charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Background:

I have a workbook which is structured as follows:

Summary sheet - holds the data bank, organised by unit code.

Worksheet(s) - formulae on these sheets report elements from the data bank to a local store on the sheet, based on the selected unit code.  Concatenation formulae report the data from the local store as part of a text string, and a simple bar chart refers to the same local store.

Iteration runs through a list of unit codes to output a series of reports unique to that unit code.  As calculation is disabled the VBA includes a Calculate function to refresh the values based on the selected unit code before outputting each report.

Issue:

From a specific code (lets call it Code Q) onward the calculate function appears to be only partly effective. Although the local store of data is successfully updated to reflect the active unit code (as evidenced by the concatenated text), some (not all) of the charts appear to be static (do not reflect the data for the active unit code but the data for Code Q) - even more intriguingly, from my POV, on some charts (scatterplots) the local store holds the correct x and y values, but the chart reflects the active code's x value and the Code Q's Y value??

Is this a VBA issue, an Excel issue or something else?

[Added code]

```
'define the name of the survey as it will appear in the filename
Dim File_Short_Name As String

File_Short_Name = InputBox("What is the SHORT title of the file - for use in the filename?")


'Defines the Source workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook

'Prompts the user for the path to the commentary files.

Set diaFolder2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder2.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder2.Title = "Where are the commentary Files?"
diaFolder2.Show

MsgBox diaFolder2.SelectedItems(1)

Dim ESPath As String

ESPath = diaFolder2.SelectedItems(1)

Set diaFolder2 = Nothing

'Define contents pages


'Define the survey long name for use in the footer
Dim File_Long_Name As String

File_Long_Name = wbSource.Worksheets("Cover (M)").Range("K6") 'added 10/8/15


'Prompts the user for the path to the commentary files.


'Iteration




'Start_code = the row number of the first unit code
'Dim i As Long

'i = InputBox("What is the row  number of the first unit to be output?") '7

Dim Start_code As Long
Start_code = Application.InputBox("What's the first row to output?", "Enter the number of the row to start the output", Type:=1)
'Start_code = Sheets("Master").Range("Start_Code").Row


'countend is the number of rows in the list 
Dim CountEnd As Long

CountEnd = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Master").Range("Unit_Codes"))


'Bespoke is the variable used for the maximum iteration
Dim ReportCount As Long

'if the following procedure fails then VBA will prompt the user and return to the input box
On Error Resume Next

'Inputbox allows user to specify the number of times to run the iteration.  the default value is Countend (the full list)
 ReportCount = Application.InputBox("How many units do you want to output?", "Enter the number of units to output", CountEnd, Type:=1)


'If the user keys in a value greater than the number of rows in the list it will override the input value and use Countend.

If ReportCount > CountEnd Then ReportCount = CountEnd


'set the number of times to perform the iteration
Dim Iterate As Long

'will run from 1 to the number selected in the input box above.

For Iterate = 1 To ReportCount

'go to Master
Sheets("Master").Activate


'set the range that holds the unit code
Dim CopyRange As String

CopyRange = "B" & Start_code 'Unit code is assumed to be in column B, using the row value for Start_Code

'copy this to C3 on the same sheet (this will trigger the updating of charts and tables in the file
Range(CopyRange).Copy Sheets("Master").Range("B2")

'Colour the cell just copied green so we know it's been copied.
Range(CopyRange).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

'Define the Unit code and name for use later on.
Dim Unit_Code As String

Unit_Code = Worksheets("Master").Range("B2").Value


'

Calculate 'force calculation of the new values

'========================================
'New code to update Scatterplot chart axes
'1 Activate sheet
'2 Select chart
'3 update chart references
'4 repeat for next sheet
'========================================

Worksheets("XXX (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_XXX_Scatter_Q3").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q3_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("YYY (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_YYY_Scatter_Q4").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q4_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_YYY_Scatter_Q5").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q5_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_YYY_Scatter_Q6").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q6_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("ZZZ (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_ZZZ_Scatter_Q7").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q7_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_ZZZ_Scatter_Q9").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q9_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_ZZZ_Scatter_Q10").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q10_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("AAA (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_AAA_Scatter_Q11").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q11_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_AAA_Scatter_Q12").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q12_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_AAA_Scatter_Q13").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q13_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("BBB (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_BBB_Scatter_Q14").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q14_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_BBB_Scatter_Q15").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q15_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_BBB_Scatter_Q16").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q16_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("CCC (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_CCC_Scatter_Q18").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q18_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_CCC_Scatter_Q19").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q19_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("DDD (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_DDD_Scatter_Q20").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q20_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_DDD_Scatter_Q22").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q22_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("EEE (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_EEE_Scatter_Q24").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q24_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_EEE_Scatter_Q26").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q26_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_EEE_Scatter_Q28").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q28_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_EEE_Scatter_Q30").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q30_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis


Worksheets("FFF (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q31").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q31_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q32").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q32_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q33").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q33_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q34").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q34_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q35").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q35_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q36").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q36_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q37").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q37_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q38").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q38_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q39").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q39_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_FFF_Scatter_Q40").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q40_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Worksheets("GGG (M)").Activate

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_GGG_Scatter_Q41").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q41_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart_GGG_Scatter_Q42").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("Min_RAG_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("Max_Rag_Variance")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = Range("Q42_Average")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis

Dim Unit_Name As String
Unit_Name = Worksheets("Master").Range("C2").Value

Worksheets("Master").Activate


'==============================
'21/1/14 Update
'Use boolean to select sheets based on Unit List for reports.

Core = False



For Each sh In Worksheets
If UCase(Right(sh.Name, 3)) = "(M)" _
Or UCase(Right(sh.Name, 3)) = "(A)" _
Then 'open name selection
If Core Then 'if name selection note found then
sh.Select (False)
Else
sh.Select (True)
Core = True
End If 'close not found option
End If 'close name selection
With sh.PageSetup
.LeftFooter = "&K02-024" & File_Long_Name & Chr(10) & Unit_Name
.CenterFooter = ""
.RightFooter = "&K02-024Page &P of &N"
.CenterHorizontally = True
.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    End With
Next sh






'define the sheets to be exported to PDF
For Each sh In Worksheets
If UCase(Right(sh.Name, 3)) = "(M)" _
Or UCase(Right(sh.Name, 3)) = "(A)" _
Then 'open name selection
If Core Then 'if name selection note found then
sh.Select (False)
Else
sh.Select (True)
Core = True
End If 'close not found option
End If 'close name selection
Next sh
'export the selected sheets to PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=SavePath & "\" & Unit_Code & " " & Unit_Name & " " & File_Short_Name & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


'update the value for i by 1
Start_code = Start_code + 1

'update the value for the unit code so that it uses the new value for i

CopyRange = "B" & Start_code

'repeat
Next Iterate
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to see your code to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Effectively the code identifies the active unit from the list, pastes that value into a key cell referenced by the other formulae in the worksheets that generate the local stores.  Once that's done the code runs "calculate" (on all open workbooks) and then selects the sheets to be outputted... All aspects of this have worked well before (over a period of a year) but in this instance the result is not as expected.

Comment: So you are saying your code has always worked but now its creating an issue? If that is not the case I would still suggest to post your code in your question as there could always be something not 100% with the code, or is there a reason why you won't or can't post?

Comment: Will post when I can access file...

Comment: resolved - the issue is Excel's ability to refresh the cached series data for charts, which apparently is finite.  Adding coding to update an aspect of the chart flushes the cached data, so refreshing the data in the chart.